# How do I block uploads that lack "DateTimeOriginal" exif data with Fine Uploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

I have an app where having the DateTimeOriginal time stamp on photos are absolutely necessary. Is there a way for me to stop uploading and display a message using Fine Uploader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of the "taken-at" tag, and I don't believe this is a standard field. The rest of this answer assumes you really do want to focus on this tag, but even if you don't you can make a simple change in the source code below to focus on another EXIF tag instead.

One approach is to check each file in an `onSubmit` callback handler and simply reject the file is it does not contain a "taken-at" field. The following example utilizes the [exif-js library](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) to parse an image file's EXIF data:

```js
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
  callbacks: {
     onSubmit: function(id) {
       var blob = this.getFile(id)
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         EXIF.getData(blob, function() {
           var takenAt = EXIF.getTag(this, 'taken-at')
           if (takenAt) {
             resolve()
           }
           else {
             reject()
           }
         })
       })
     } 
   }
})
```

Comment: You're right, the exif field was DateTimeOriginal. taken_at was my db column for it.

Comment: I tried out this code and it didn't work. I added a bunch of console.log lines and found that it works right up to var blob = this.getFile(id); and then stops. There's no other output in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: I can console log the id as well. Returns 0, 1, etc but this.getFile stalls out without any output and the script stops.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Now my only issue is it doesn't display anything on rejecting the file, it just doesn't add it to the object list. Can you point me in the right direction for extending this further?

Comment: Along with rejecting, you can and probably should display your own user message, using a library or approach that best fits your application.