# How can I pass object specific params on uploadSuccess with FineUploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

To piggyback on my previous question here:

[How do I block uploads that lack "DateTimeOriginal" exif data with Fine Uploader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411117/how-do-i-block-uploads-that-lack-taken-at-exif-data-with-fine-uploader)

Once I've got the exif data, I'd like to pass it on to my server within the uploadSuccess AJAX call.

I'm aware of being able to add params, but what I don't see in the docs is some way to do something like:

```
uploadSuccess: {
   params: function(id) {
      var params = {
         DateTimeOriginal: timestamps[id]
      }
      return params;
   }
}
```

Is there an equivalent way to handle this?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question

Comment: @RayNicholus According to the docs, there doesn't appear to be a way to reference the object ID in the uploadSuccess call to the server. I'm getting the exif data onSubmit, and I'd like to send that in the params with the uploadSuccess call but I'm not sure how to get the id of the object to use it as a key.

Comment: @RayNicholus A dirty way to do it would be to send an array of all of the Exif data I collected with every uploadSuccess call, since the call automatically sends the object id to the server I can reference it by key server side. But I'd rather not send unnecessary data if I can help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon deeper documentation digging, I found this method:

```
this.setUploadSuccessParams
```

Which does the trick.

http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods-s3.html#setUploadSuccessParams